# Naming words that are grouped

Tags: copywriting, filter

We have multiple lists of words that have been grouped by our users. They use the groupings later to filter. We're having a hard time titling the Filter and the action of Grouping.

"Group" cannot be used because it is already a term we use in the interface.

Any thoughts or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: For what purpose do users group those words? How are the words within groups related to each other? Have you tried looking into a thesaurus for synonyms of "group"?

Comment: It might be a good idea posting this at [StackExchange English](http://english.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Each user has a lexicon they add to our system that we then use to for culling data. When one of these terms comes up we flag it for the user so they can act on it. Users needed a way to group words in their lexicon so they could filter the returned data by many words that have similar associations rather than one word at a time.

Comment: We have done a thesaurus check for synonyms. I think the problem is we're finding that the words have little meaning. I guess we need to provide a contextual word.

Answer (score 3):

How about category, collection, set, or items?

Comment: or cluster as well.

Comment: Thanks. I think we are going to go with Set, with a adjective in front of it to describe what the sets are for.

Answer (score 0):

I think collection or box might be the best solutions, 
you can use collect als verb for the filter.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the action you're describing is *filter by word cloud, filter semantically* or something like that.

You might have a heading called **Filter,** followed by a field labeled **Find a word cloud.** Have a field hint "enter a word to get started," or whatever is the appropriate action.

If your word clouds are mutually exclusive, entering a single word could bring up a dropdown of related words in the cloud. If your words are not exclusive to one group or another, make that field a [combo-box](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/3110/a-cross-between-a-dropdownlist-and-autocomplete-text-box) and let people multi-select words that fit, and filter by all groups that include those words.

[image: example wireframe]

Answer (score -1):

Without knowing anything more about what brings the groups of words together, the community will probably not be more able to find a name for them than this theusaurus:

http://www.synonyms.net/synonym/group

On the other hand, if you were able to say what they were if not groups, then you would already have the answer. :)

Comment: The words in the lexicon are for enterprise compliance. For any give enterprise, there might be terms around government regulations (for example FINRA) or brand compliance or swear words. The users would like to group these terms together for quicker searches since the entire lexicon might contain upwards of 500 terms. Does that clarify it any?

Comment: Yes, a little. :) What is the main purpose of the software?

Comment: It's a social media management tool.

Comment: After receiving a notice "We're looking for long answers..." I added some explanation to my link.